# Finding max value in another column for each unique value in a column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get the max start for each id, this is the table that I have:

```
    id        descrip   start
0   0000      x         4
1   0000      y         60
2   1111      x         7
3   1111      x         0
4   2222      z         452
5   3333      x         36622
6   3333      t         32
```

And this is what I want:

```
    id        descrip   start
0   0000      y         60
1   1111      x         7
2   2222      z         452
3   3333      x         36622
```

I tried doing this

```
df.loc[df.reset_index().groupby(['id'])['start'].idxmax()]
```

But i have been getting this error:

```
KeyError: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike'
```

Comment: `df.groupby('id').max()` should do it. If you want to get indices for max elements `df.groupby('id').idxmax()`

Comment: You read about the error [`Indexing with list with missing labels is deprecated¶
`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-with-list-with-missing-labels-is-deprecated)